# java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompatJellyBeanMr2.class

Tags: android, android-studio, duplicates, android-multidex

I am integrating my project into another app in android studio but it shows the below error, I am googling the issue but no use.

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageAllDebugClassesForMultiDex'.
> java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompatJellyBeanMr2.class
```

below is my app dependencies

```
configurations { all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations' }
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile project(':waleteros')
        compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:+'
       compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:5.1.2'
    compile files('src/libs/android_sync_service_library.jar')
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services:3.1.+"
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.2.2@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
```

and here is my library dependencies

```
configurations { all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4' }
configurations { all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations' }
dependencies {
    compile project(':ingosdk')
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
    compile files('libs/A2iA.Mobility.jar')
    compile files('libs/acra-4.5.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/bugsense-3.5.jar')
    compile files('libs/deviceprint-lib-1.0.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/FlurryAnalytics-5.3.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpmime-4.1.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/libGoogleAnalyticsServices.jar')
    compile files('libs/volley.jar')
    compile 'com.actionbarsherlock:actionbarsherlock:4.4.0@aar'
    compile files('libs/android-support-v13.jar')

}
```

Comment: appcompat-v4 is defined twice somewhere. You have to explore your dependencies to find it.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. Help

Comment: in my case i have deleted support plugin from gradle and i deleted also jar file from libs

Answer (score 12):

If you have the android-support-v4.jar in your libs folder.. delete it!

That solved my problem.

Even though the file is not added in the build.gradle file.. gradle includes it in the build anyway.

Comment: Thanks, you saved my day! :)

Comment: i didnt find any android-support-v4.jar in my libs folder.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem after upgrading the android SDK. I was able to run the application in the `buildToolsVersion '23.0.1'`, I got the same error when I changed to `buildToolsVersion '24.0.3'`

I resolved the problem by updating my java version from `1.7 to 1.8` with `compileSdkVersion 24`

Answer (score 1):

Similar issue, I'd just imported

```
compile 'fr.avianey.com.viewpagerindicator:library:2.4.1.1'
```

and was getting this error, after adding "@aar", the problem was solved

```
compile 'fr.avianey.com.viewpagerindicator:library:2.4.1.1@aar'
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion this error is happened by duplicate jar file.
I delete my support-V4 jar file into my library and then clean build it works fine.
Thanks