# Android App Crashes on Tablet

Tags: java, android, android-studio, tablet

I have a working Android app which runs well on mobile phones. I tried to run the app on my tablet.

I got this message -

```
Instant Run does not support deploying build variants with multidex enabled, 
to a target with API level 20 or below.To use Instant Run with a multidex 
enabled build variant, deploy to a target with API level 21 or higher.
```

and got this error during build

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
 com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: 
 duplicate entry: android/support/v13/app/FragmentCompatICS.class
```

So, I connected my phone, Build and Run the app on my phone. It worked fine. I know that Android Studio generated apk file. So, I copied the apk file to my tablet and installed it but the app crashed with the dialog "Unfortunately stopped".

What is causing this crash and how do I solve it?

Comment: What version of Android is running on your tablet?  Have you tried setting your target API to 21 or higher?

Comment: Tab runs 4.4.2 i.e API 19

Comment: it doesn't crash on the rablet. It even doesn't get built. It doesn't relate to the tablet at all. it's all about your app sources (containing duplicate classes)

Comment: Can you elaborate? I dont think I have duplicate classes

Comment: Seems odd that you could build and run on your phone but not your tablet.  If it really is a duplicate class you may need to delete any extra support jars - see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30937525/java-util-zip-zipexception-duplicate-entry-android-support-v4-accessibilityser).  You might also try bumping up your target API to the latest version.  You can [read more about that here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html).

Comment: Your tablet is running an older version of android than API 21

Comment: @cricket_007 My minSdk is set to 16. So, it should run

Comment: It's the target sdk, as the error states